# RemoteViewAdapter method returning NULL error?

Tags: android

Whenever i run this method for my StackView...

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);


    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(stackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
    Intent fillnIntent = new Intent();
    fillnIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item, fillnIntent);
    rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.wigdetView, bm);
    MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
    myTask.execute();


    //Do heavy lifting here, Downloading images from a network or website.

    return rv ;
}
```

I get this error in the debug..

```
08-01 19:48:00.520: ERROR/RemoteViewsAdapter(14319): Error in updateRemoteViews(24): null
08-01 19:48:05.530: ERROR/AppWidgetService(131): Error (unbindRemoteViewsService): Connection not bound
```

Here is my updateRemoteiews() here...

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for(int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.stack_view, intent);

        rv.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_view, R.id.add);

        Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, stackWidgetProvider.class);
        toastIntent.setAction(stackWidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
        toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, toastPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
    }
```

What could the problem be??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this same issue and my problem was that the images that I was loading were too big. After commenting out the code for the images, my problem went away, so now I have to look for a workaround for that (I'm looking for a solution at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/bp8ddUGHGhE).

This error is also accompanied by a "FAILED Binder Transaction" in the log cat.